# Can a body move in a particular direction without having any apparent force in that direction?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque

I was brushing off my rotational mechanics when I thought of this hypothetical scenario. The wheel has a mass m and is supposed to climb up the step by the application of some horizontal force at S. Given that the point of contact acts at a fixed axis to rotate about (there is enough friction to prevent slipping), will the wheel climb up the step even though it doesn't have any net vertical force to climb up the step?[image]